# Function For Multiple Exponents

Tags: number-theory

Multiplication is of the form $ab = \sum_{i=1}^b a$ Exponents are of the form $a^b = \prod_{i=1}^b a$ is there a function $f(a, b)$ which is $a$ to the power of itself $b$ times. For example $f(4, 3)$ is 4 to the power of 4 to the power of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The **Tetration operation**. Defined recursively as
$$^na=\begin{cases}1& n=0\\^{(^{n-1}a)}a & \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Knuth express this as $$a\uparrow \uparrow n,$$
called the **Up-arrow** notation